# Reg expression - URL redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a url which is

`http://www.meadowsryan.co.uk/team/piers-meadows/` or

`http://www.meadowsryan.co.uk/team/david-rogers/` or

`http://www.meadowsryan.co.uk/team/graham-hunt/`

I want to use a wildcard regexpr so that all urls go to

`http://www.meadowsryan.co.uk/team/piers-meadows/?team_cpt=IMT_PAGE_TEMPLATE`
`http://www.meadowsryan.co.uk/team/david-rogers/?team_cpt=IMT_PAGE_TEMPLATE`
`http://www.meadowsryan.co.uk/team/graham-hunt/?team_cpt=IMT_PAGE_TEMPLATE`

This is a WordPress site. I am presuming I can put the redirect rule somewhere in my `.htaccess` file